# sed search multiple strings in one file

Tags: linux, sed

I want to search multiple strings in the same file
So far I have this working but one string only

```
sed -n '/XXX/,+1p'  FILE > FILE
```

But I want

```
sed -n '/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/,+1p'  FILE > FILE
```

I could not make it work.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a programming question; as far as I'm concerned this belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tink - These questions are fertilizer that help the cucumbers grow...

Comment: @jww - tsk-tsk-tsk :0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\|` to separate multiple patterns to match.

```
sed -n '/XXX\|YYY\|ZZZ/,+1p'  INFILE > OUTFILE
```

Also, the input file has to be different from the output file (if you want to overwrite the file you should use the `-i` option rather than redirecting to the input file).